# Connecting to Web Deployment Service - Service not runing error

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-deployment

I have just created AWS account and trying free tier services. I have created a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Express and IIS.

I have added my application to iis as usual. Now trying to deploy my app from Visual Studio and getting error:

> Couln't connect to remote computer ("XXXX"). On the remote computer
>   make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process
>   ("Web management service") is started.

Web Deploy 3.5 is installed and Web management service is running. Any idea why i can't deploy this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like required software is pre-installed but ports are closed. For those who will face with same problem:

http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/hosting-the-microsoft-web-platform-on-amazon-ec2/amazon-ec2-microsoft-web-platform-images-full-web-server-development-stack

You need to open the port 8172 from Security group options in **AWS panel**.